# Wix Syntax Error

Tags: syntax, wix

I used

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
xmlns:util='http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension'
xmlns:fire='http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/FirewallExtension'
>
```

On compiling my code i get error the error is as below

```
error CNDL0200 : The Component element contains an unhandled extension element 'fire:FirewallException'.  Please ensure that the extension for elements in the 'http://schemas.microsoft.com /wix/FirewallExtension' namespace has been provided.
```

What is wrong with my syntax

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Have you added a reference to the project?

Comment: I added a reference. Now it works

Comment: Great can you mark the answer as answered...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to add "FirewallExtension" reference to the project.